# MacVIM not displaying tab/buffer line in Fullscreen mode on OSX Captain

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I used `:Fullscreen` command to send the MacVIM to full-screen mode. (This is a function in "vim-shell" written by xolox, available on Github through the author.)

Everything worked fine (I started Vim graphically through `mvim` command), except for a vanishing `tabline` (or the buffer line). While I can see the tabs opened in the current (graphical) Vim instance, I cannot find any display of tab-line in the Fullscreen mode. This was not a problem when I was using the same set of plug-ins on a Windows machine.

I have specified the following set of options, but nothing was displayed:

```
set showtabline=2
```

Additionally, I have also tried to render the "tabline" through `Vim-Airline`, but still failed the full-screen mode.

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_buffers = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_tab_nr = 1
```

A similar problem was found as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057835/macvim-in-yosemite-cant-fullscreen, however, the solution proposed was for Yosemite and did not appear to be helpful for my case, on a OSX Captain system.

Thank you!